# Using DataFrame.apply with a lambda function to assign returned tuple/list to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which takes a single input and returns a list of two values

```
def my_func(x):
    return [x+1, x+2]
```

Say I have a simple dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I'd like to apply my_func to each value of column 'x' and then save the returned values in column 'y' and column 'z' respectively, something like:

```
(df['y'], df['z']) = df.apply(lambda row: my_func(row.x), axis = 1)
```

obviously this doesn't work..

What's the best way to go about this?

**Edit**: as @Andy Hayden pointed out below, in this case I can simply use

```
df['y'], df['z'] = myfunc(df.x)
```

That's because `myfunc` does a very simple vector calculation here. What if it's more complicated?

```
dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e', 6:'f'}
def my_func(x):
    return [dict[x], dict[x+1]]
```

So here, `dict[x]` can't work on the entire series any more and I guess I'll have to use `apply` ? then again, how do put the result into two individual columns of a dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to do an apply here:

```
In [11]: df["y"], df["z"] = my_func(df.x)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. but that's probably due to `my_func` is quite simple here, what if `my_func` does something that is not as simple as vector calculation

Comment: @Godsent If your function passed to apply returns a Series (for each row) then the index of that Series can be assigned as columns. i.e. pd.Series([dict[x], dict[x+1]])